# Selecting three of Max() values of a field in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume that i have three field in my database like this :

```
ID    Title    MaxVisited

 1     hi          6
 2     bye         8
 3     How?        9
 4     News!       8
 5     Hey         3
 6     Thanks      9
```

now i want to  select Title three of max value of MaxVisited.. the result which i want:

```
Thanks , How? , News!
```

Comment: How/Why is `News!` selected in preference to `bye`?

Comment: yeah, `bye` and `news!` have same value (`8`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the top 3 and order by `MaxVisited` and (if necessary) the `Id` column

```
SELECT TOP 3 Title from [TableName] 
order by MaxVisited, Id desc
```

Comment: Maybe, right. I included the id column to ensure the requested result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 3 Title 
From [TableName] 
order by MaxVisited,Title desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 3 Title from [your_table] 
order by MaxVisited, ID desc
```